# Remove span from a html output

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to remove a `span` tag from a html output.

Say like i have a variable `template` which holds a html output.

```
<li id="GRP_1" data-role="list-divider">Group 1<span id="121" onclick="deleteGroup(this.id);" class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow li-divider-icon-right">&nbsp;</span></li>
```

In the above html output i want to remove/hide the span tag. If possible give me a solution for both hide & remove that span tag. Find the fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krrr25/GWzPp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in many different ways.

By id:

`$('#121').hide();` or `$('#121').remove();`

By html element:

`$('span').hide();` or `$('span').remove();`

And by class:

`$('ui-icon.ui-icon-delete.ui-icon-shadow.li-divider-icon-right').hide();`

or

`$('ui-icon.ui-icon-delete.ui-icon-shadow.li-divider-icon-right').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#121').hide();

$('#121').remove();
```

I recommend you to change the id from numbers to letters or letters + numbers. Or add a unique class to your span.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li span').remove();

$('li span').hide();
```

Comment: If you remove the elements from the DOM there is no need to hide them. They no longer exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
$('#GRP_1').find('span').hide();
$('#GRP_1').find('span').show();
```